# Callback in python script

Tags: python, ajax, json, api, callback

I've never used python before. Thus, I'm kind of confused. I'm trying to use python script to obtain data from the education api. I'm unsure as to how I would accomplish this. I have the following python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Import modules for CGI handling 
import cgi, cgitb
import urllib2 

# Create instance of FieldStorage 
form = cgi.FieldStorage() 

#download data from request parameter 'url' 
print "Content-type:text/xml\r\n\r\n"  
url = form.getvalue("url") 
callback = form.getvalue("callback")
req = urllib2.Request(url) 
response = urllib2.urlopen(req) 
data = response.read() 
print callback + "(" + data+ ")"
```

I know I would replace the url in this text with url of the website I'm requesting the data from. However, what do I replace callback with?

I also understand I will need make a ajax call to retrieve the json data in my browser. How would I do this?

The code I have to return the json is the following:

```
$.ajax({
url : "getData.py",
data : {url : "http://api.education.com/service/service.php?f=schoolSearch&key=mykey&
sn=sf&v=4&city=Atlanta&state=ga&Resf=json"},
complete : function(xhr, result) {
if (result != "success")
return;
var response = xhr;
console.log(var);
```

Comment: If you've never used Python before, I would strongly suggest first writing a standalone program to access the API, and only then try to wrap it in a CGI. (Actually, I wouldn't use CGI at all; modern WSGI is easier and more powerful, and also has more up-to-date tutorials to help you get started.)

Comment: Meanwhile, it's not clear what exactly your code is supposed to do. Give us a link to whatever tutorial or sample you copied and pasted from, and we can probably guess what's supposed to happen. Without that, it's next to impossible.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a reference to the JSONP syntax commonly in use to bypass cross domain security restriction that are part of the browser. You can think of this as an interaction in the following format:

```
standard request:
  url => json payload

jsonp request:
  url?callback=something => something(json_payload)
```

jQuery will normally fill the callback parameter in for you if you pass the

```
dataType: "jsonp"
```

flag to your ajax request as noted in this documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

so the answer to your question about the callback parameter is "whatever method you want to handle the response". This is strictly used in the JavaScript environment to make the request across domains without the benefit of an intermediary. If you are using a Python proxy to make this request (which is appears you may be able to do) you can just leave the callback parameter off to retrieve the standard json data payload and return that value to the requesting client.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I found clear extensive examples in [this](https://www.advsofteng.com/doc/cdpydoc/dbsample2.htm) website

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Import modules for CGI handling 
import cgi, cgitb
import urllib2 

# Create instance of FieldStorage 
form = cgi.FieldStorage() 

#download data from request parameter 'url' 
print "Content-type:text/xml\n"  
url = form["url"].value
callback = form["callback"].value
req = urllib2.Request(url) 
response = urllib2.urlopen(req) 
data = response.read() 
print callback + "(" + data.replace("\n", "\\n") + ")"
```

The client side code

```
$.ajax({
url : "/cgi-bin/getData.py",
data : {url : "http://api.education.com/service/service.php?f=schoolSearch&key=mykey&
sn=sf&v=4&city=Atlanta&state=ga&Resf=json"},
complete : function(xhr, result) {
if (result != "success")
return;
var response = xhr;
console.log(var);
```